# Gson Deserialization Issue With UTF-16

Tags: java, json, utf-8, gson, utf-16

I'm having an issue with this line of code:

```
try (OutputStreamWriter fileout = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(Paths.get(path.toString(), TAGS_FILE.toString()).toString()), "UTF-16")) {
    fileout.write(gson.toJson(imageList, listType));
    fileout.flush();
    fileout.close();
}
```

I was using UTF-8 originally and it was working fine, loaded fine and everything, but had to change to UTF-16 to preserve some special characters. It still writes out the file correctly, exact same as with UTF-8 (except with the special characters in-tact), but when it tries to load the file into another session I get "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING..."

Is there a way around this?

Also, if this helps:

```
private final Type listType = new TypeToken<TreeSet<MyClass>>(){}.getType();
TreeSet<MyClass> imageList;
```

UPDATE:

```
private void move(File file, Path destination, boolean autoTag) {
    String fileName = file.getName();
    Matcher numberMatcher = leadingNumbersPattern.matcher(fileName);

    // remove leading numbers 
    while (numberMatcher.find()) {
        fileName = clean(fileName, leadingNumbersPattern);
    }

    Matcher artistMatcher = artistPattern.matcher(fileName);
    Matcher newFileNameMatcher = newFileNamePattern.matcher(fileName);

    if (artistMatcher.find() && newFileNameMatcher.find()) {
        // set artist name
        String artist = artistMatcher.group().substring(0, artistMatcher.group().length() - 1);
        // set new picture name
        String newFileName = newFileNameMatcher.group().substring(1);

        Path newPath = Paths.get(destination.toString(), artist);                       // path to artist folder
        new File(newPath.toString()).mkdirs();                                          // make artist folder
        newPath = Paths.get(destination.toString(), artist, newFileName);               // make path to new file location

        try {
            Files.move(file.toPath(), newPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);    // move file to new location
            MyImage newImage = new MyImage(newPath.toString(), artist, newFileName);
```

Comment: UTF-8 is supposed to represent *all* characters in the Unicode standard. Perhaps it would be best to tackle the original problem rather than a new one.

Comment: Well @RealSkeptic I ran into Thai characters...it was saving as...not Thai characters in the json file. If you have a suggestion for getting it to write the characters correctly I'd be more than happy.

Comment: First, the standard json is supposed to support any characters in the format `\uXXXX`. So even a JSON in US-ASCII can have characters in Thai or whatever script. But can [edit] your question and add an example class that writes to the  file, the resulting JSON and what you expected?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Update: My class sorts files into folders based on their name. I have a function that can readd already sorted files, which I just tried and it correctly wrote the characters in UTF-8, which means there's an issue in the original sorting. I've updated the question with that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing back to UTF-8 fixed the issue. I had to remake the json file; I guess the Thai characters had somehow slipped through when I converted everything to UTF-8 originally.

EDIT:
Found the cause! The load() method I was using to deserialize the file wasn't set to use UTF-8 on the FileInputStream. Adding this fixed the issue completely.